# Return reference to list element to be able to assign a value to it

Tags: c#

I came from C++ background and have a simple problem here. I have the following List as a class member:

```
public enum FieldColor {Empty, Blue, White};
private List<List<FieldColor>> m_board = new List<List<FieldColor>>();
```

Now I have such a simple method:

```
private FieldColor GetFieldColor(GridCoordinates coordinates) {
    return m_board[coordinates.row][coordinates.column];
}
```

Now I want to use this method to assign value to a `coordinate` and I have wrote this:

```
    GetFieldColor(coordinates) = color;
```

And I get this error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer [Assembly-CSharp]

What is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use a [Ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#what-is-a-reference-return-value)

> Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports reference return values (ref
>   returns). A reference return value allows a method to return a
>   reference to a variable, rather than a value, back to a caller. The
>   caller can then choose to treat the returned variable as if it were
>   returned by value or by reference. The caller can create a new
>   variable that is itself a reference to the returned value, called a
>   ref local.

**Limitations**

> There are some restrictions on the expression that a method can return
>   as a reference return value. Restrictions include:
>
> - The return value must have a lifetime that extends beyond the execution of the method. In other words, it cannot be a local variable
>     in the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field
>     of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting
>     to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot
>     return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."
> - The return value cannot be the literal null. Returning null generates compiler error CS8156, "An expression cannot be used in this
>     context because it may not be returned by reference."
> - A method with a ref return can return an alias to a variable whose value is currently the null (uninstantiated) value or a nullable type
>     for a value type.
> - The return value cannot be a constant, an enumeration member, the by-value return value from a property, or a method of a class or
>     struct. Violating this rule generates compiler error CS8156, "An
>     expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be
>     returned by reference."

**Example**

```
private ref int GetFieldColor(GridCoordinates coordinates)
{
    return ref m_board[coordinates.row][coordinates.column];
}
```

**Valid usage**

```
GetFieldColor(gridCoordinates) = 345;
```

---

Or you could user an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. The indexed value can be set or retrieved without explicitly
>   specifying a type or instance member. Indexers resemble properties
>   except that their accessors take parameters.

```
public int this[GridCoordinates coordinates]
{
   get => m_board[coordinates.row][coordinates.column];
   set => m_board[coordinates.row][coordinates.column] = value;
}
```

**Usage**

```
this[GridCoordinates] = 345
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a separate setter method for the same

```
private FieldColor SetFieldColor(GridCoordinates coordinates, FieldColor color) {
    m_board[coordinates.row][coordinates.column] = color;
}
```

Comment: What about this? `var correspondingBoardCell = GetFieldColor(coordinates);
  correspondingBoardCell = color;`

Comment: @Narek That wouldn't work, since you are modifying the reference `correspondingBoardCell` and not the referenced object

Answer (score 1):

You can also overload the `[]` operator to fill your needs. I find this approach less hacky than a `ref return` and more in the C# philosophy.

```
public FieldColor this[int row, int column]
{
    get => m_board[row][column];
    set => m_board[row][column] = value;
}
```

If needed, a second overload which uses the previous one:

```
public FieldColor this[GridCoordinates coordinates]
{
    get => this[coordinates.row, coordinates.column];
    set => this[coordinates.row, coordinates.column] = value;
}
```

Usage:

```
field[0, 1] = FieldColor.Empty;
var color = field[0, 1];
```